# Didn't identify the httpMethod at aws Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I am binding the apis from aws but didn't httpMethod didnot Identified I didn't get why this happen? I already mapped the integration request in get request of api-gateway. Is there something that I missed?

Lambda function is shown below:

```
exports.handleHttpRequest = function (request, context, callback) {
    console.log('---------', request, request.httpMethod);
    switch (request.httpMethod) {
        case 'GET': {
        
            callback(null, "get case run");
            break;
        }
        case 'POST': {
            callback(null, "post Case run");
            break;
        }
        default:
            callback(null, "run default case");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in this link here at stackoverflow:

[How to get the HTTP method in AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252544/how-to-get-the-http-method-in-aws-lambda)

You need to send it throught context object from API Gateway > Mapping Tempates. Then you can just invoke the **context.httpMethod** available at your Lambda function.

You can find it here at [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html).